# Fast Java library for language detection of Tweets?

Tags: java, twitter, translation, language-detection

According to this bug, Twitter's search API has been broken with regard to Language for at least 2 years: http://bit.ly/GQ244g so it seems unlikely they're going to fix it.

I've looked at the libraries mentioned on the other language detection threads, and they all look great and offer 95%+ accuracy. The question is, which one to use for Tweets?

I suspect that Tweets may be challenging because they're composed of language plus hashtags, which are typically in English. Additionally, my primary concern is performance. I don't mind losing a few Tweets if I can perform the filtering faster.

So my question is for those who have done language detection on Tweets: What library did you use, and what performance did you observe?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [language-detection](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/)? It claims 99% precision for 53 languages. However, given that tweets are generally short I'm afraid that you can just dream of such a high precision...  You should try to generate your own language profiles out of twitter training data and with a subset of languages if possible (you need to do a bit of research on this). I don't know much about performances and it might be better if you can write your own tests.

EDIT:
Take a look at this Python project as well, you might want to try some integration with your java code base: https://github.com/shuyo/ldig

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Apache Tika.
Can be useful for a bunch of other things beyond just language detection:

http://tika.apache.org/1.5/detection.html#Language_Detection

Answer (score 1):

You may use Microsoft's translator webservice from Java. https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/1899a118-d202-492c-aa16-ba21c33c06cb (its free for 2.000.000 words per month and offers language detection)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. The primary concern I have with using any online webservice to do this (including Google's) is that the network latency alone is going to push performance beyond the acceptable range. I'm really looking for a Java library that I can run locally.

Comment: Then a very hard task waiting for you

Answer (score 1):

You should use [JLangDetect](http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/jlangdetect_0_3_released_with). I cannot recommend anything more than this.